# NavBar displaying back twice when app changed to landscape mode

Tags: iphone, landscape, xib

Not sure what's going on here, but my iPhone apps nav bar shows back and the title of my detail view controller even when I'm back to the original view. It wasn't happening earlier, it has changed recently (but not sure when exactly).

E.g. I click on a row, view the didSelectRow XIB and then click back on the NavBar controller, but it still shows back even though the view does change back to the original table view. I then have to press back again and then it clears.

Update: It's as if its trying to go back three times instead of two. Because, if you visit another row without removing the back button, it stores it as if you need to go back twice.

It works fine in portrait mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the sdk version u are using and if there is any titleview associated with your navigation bar ?

Comment: I'm using 3.1.3 and yes there is a titleview. But once again, it only affects the nav bar in landscape mode.

Comment: Never mind - I found the issue. I hadn't set all the tables to autorotate, and as such their views were still attempting to stay portrait! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all the tables had been set to auto-rotate, so their views were still staying portrait.